# How do I set guess constraints for a solution of a linear system of equation?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, programming, linear-algebra

Let's say I have a linear system of equations  $$ Ax = \biggl( \begin{matrix} 1 & 2\\ 0 &1\\ \end{matrix} \biggr) \biggl(\begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{matrix} \biggr) = \biggl( \begin{matrix} 11 \\ 4 \end{matrix} \biggr).$$
The answer is $$ x = \biggl( \begin{matrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{matrix} \biggr). $$ But what if I couldn't solve for x directly because A is large and badly conditioned, but I am 95% sure that $$ 1 \leq x_1 \leq 10 \\ 1 \leq x_2 \leq 7, $$ and both $x_1, x_2$ are integers.

How can I use Mathematica to solve or guess for x, given A, b, and $$\\$$ a) an arbitrary set of constraints for an range for each $x_i,$
and/or $$\\$$b) an arbitrary integer range for each $x_i,$ given that all $x_i$ are integers?
$$\\$$
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template for solving `A.x = b` with constraints is:

Solve[A.x == b && *constraints*..., *variables*, *domain*]

For your example, `Solve` finds solutions over the domain of integers, with constraints for x1 and x2, where && is [logical AND](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/And.html).

```
A = {{1, 2}, {0, 1}};
x = {{x1}, {x2}};
b = {{11}, {4}};

Solve[A.x == b && 1 <= x1 <= 10 && 1 <= x2 <= 7, {x1, x2}, Integers]
```

> ```
> {{x1 -> 3, x2 -> 4}}
> ```

Comment: `x` and `b` can be defined more simply as `x = {x1, x2};
b = {11, 4};` You will get the same result.

Comment: It's a linear problem though, so the constraints are superfluous.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, but the issue is how to apply constraints and integer domain to a large and badly conditioned `A`. The simple example is not the reason for the question. Have I missed something?

Comment: This solves my problem! Thanks so much!

Comment: (1) If the system is linear then most (maybe all) methods will be unable to use constraints to the solutions. Possible exceptions are indirect methods e.g. Krylov where constraints might be used for initial guesses.

Comment: (2) What might work better is to recast as a linear (possibly integer) program where the constraints will be used, and have objective function be some measure of "failure to satisfy" the equalities you want to enforce.